# Hibernate Java automized serialization to database

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Let's assume that we have entity Entry and EntryComment related as Many-to-one as shown below

```
      @Entity
        @Table(name = "entry")
        public class Entry {
            @Column(name = "author")
            private String author;
            @Column(name = "content")
            private String body;
            @Column(name = "comment_count")
            private long commentCount;
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entry")
            private List<EntryComment> comments;
        }
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "entry_comment")
    public class EntryComment{
        @Column(name = "vote_count")
        private long voteCount;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Entry entry;
        @Column(name = "entry_id")
        private long entryId;
}
```

Both `Entry` and `EntryComments` have id's. So, there is situation, where `entryId = 3213`, and it's comments' id's are `id = 3214` and `id = 42352`. For now I'm collecting EntryComments that way:

```
Entry e = api.getEntryString(i);
e = EntryService.save(e);
for(int a = 0; a<e.getComments().size(); a++){
     EntryComment ec = EntryCommentService.save(e.getComments().get(a));
}
```

Is that possible in Hibernate so serialize Comments right from Entry without iterating collection 'manually'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid iteration of EntryComments Collection I had to use `@Cascade` annotation. According to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/) it should be

```
      @Entity
        @Table(name = "entry")
        public class Entry {
            @Column(name = "author")
            private String author;
            @Column(name = "content")
            private String body;
            @Column(name = "comment_count")
            private long commentCount;
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entry")
            @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
            private List<EntryComment> comments;
        }
```

and then just

```
Entry e = api.getEntryString(i);
e = EntryService.save(e);
```

Thanks, [Riadh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750098/riadh) for hint!